# Не обновляется компонент при обновлении Array state

Tags: массивы, reactjs, объекты, state, setstate

Я создаю приложение на React и мне понадобилось редактировать отдельно взятые элементы в списке объектов:

```
export  default  function Component() {
    const [dialogs, setDialogs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setDialogs([
             {lastMessage: 'fff'}, 
             {lastMessage: 'dd'}, 
             {lastMessage: 'a'}
         ]);
    }, [setDialogs]);

    function editLastMessage(index) {
        let edited = dialogs;

        edited[index].lastMessage = 'dsad';
        setDialogs(edited);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
                dialogs.map((element, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <Test lastMessage={dialogs[index].lastMessage}/>
                            <button onClick={() => editLastMessage(index)}>click me!</button>
                        </div>
                     );
                 })
             }
         </div>
     );
}
```

как мне изменить state[index] так, чтобы компонент автоматически обновлялся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я решил ошибку.

```
let edited = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dialogs));
```

Оказывается, я изменял сам state по ссылке, что сломало re-render React